# Need to call exit() twice to exit when working with thread and signal handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, python-multithreading

I stumble upon pice of code that is a bit werid, I'm expecting when the program is signaled, the `exit()` should raise `SystemExit` once and cause the program to exit, however in this case, when the main thread is blocking on `th.join()`, the `exit()` statement needs be called twice for the program to exit.

It is not a practical exercise, but I want to know what is going on under the hood.

```py
import threading
import time
import signal


def task():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def sig_handler(self, *_):
    # raise ValueError()
    exit()

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    th = threading.Thread(target=task)
    th.start()
    th.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, our main program implicitly waits until all other threads have completed their work. Using daemon threads is useful for services where there may not be an easy way to interrupt the thread or where letting the thread die in the middle of its work without losing or corrupting data. to set a thread as a daemon that runs without blocking the main program from exiting. use setDaemon() method. Your main function will be:

```
def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    th = threading.Thread(target=task)
    th.setDaemon(True)
    th.start()
    th.join()
```